# Sqlite Time Function to Display Milliseconds

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, time

I have the below select statement, utilizing the 'time' function of Sqlite. The string that is being manipulated is `2013-10-09 10:17:39.406` as an example.

```
select time(table.published_time) as New_Time, ...
```

The time function removes the date from this string, but also removes the millisecond accuracy. Is there a way this can be modified to remove date but keep the milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time()` behaves like described in [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

> The time() function returns the time as HH:MM:SS.

But you can skip the call to `time()`. Use the string value directy as input to `strftime()`.

```
sqlite> select strftime('%H:%M:%f', '2013-10-09 10:17:39.406');
10:17:39.406
```

**Edit**

`%f` formats the seconds *and* the fraction:

```
sqlite> select strftime('%S - %f', '2013-10-09 10:17:39.406');
39 - 39.406
```

So `%S` should be skipped if `%f` is used.

Comment: Do you know why the seconds row is being repeated? as you can see above, .39 should only appear once.

Answer (score 1):

How about this :-

```
sqlite> select strftime('%H:%M:%f', '2013-10-09 10:17:39.406') as New_Time
   ...> ;
10:17:39.406
```

See : http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Do you know why the seconds row is being repeated? as you can see above, .39 should only appear once.

Comment: Interesting that someone edited my response to an incorrect one :). Rolled it back.

Comment: the solution you rolled back to works fine. Thanks for your help